# vertical line on the middle of the page

Tags: html, css

I need a vertical line on the middle of the page, here above i've got horizontal. What i really want is a vertical line with same style of this horizontal line.

```
hr.style-six {
    border: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

How could that be done?

EDIT:

the below codes work but i cannot add anything until the vertical line ends, from the point it ends i can add stuffs but not before that.

I'm trying to add things on the right and left side of the vertical line.
How could i fix it?

Comment: With that style, by my opinion, you'll never achieve that. You have to set `position,left,top,bottom` and you need `border`, maybe `z-index`, too.

Comment: You need separated left and right side for adding something/anything?

Comment: check my update. is that what You want?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since elements in HTML are rendered from top to bottom, there's no way of adding a vertical line as easily as using a `<hr>`. One way would be to split up the page in two `<div>`s and adding a border to one of the two `<div>`s like this:

```css
.left-col {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 200px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.right-col {
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 200px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class='page'>
  <div class='left-col'>
    Content in the left column
  </div>
  <div class='right-col'>
    Content in the right column
  </div>
</div>
```

You could also use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: right`, but it will have some issues with spaces taking up a part of the 100% width (so you can't use 50% + 50% divs without using hacks). CSS-Tricks has some [information on inline-block](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Depending on if you need content to the right of the vertical line, you may of course skip the `.right-col` entirely.

`box-sizing: border-box` makes the 1px border count as a part of the width, so that we can have 50% + 50% = 100%.

Comment: You can very easily do that with my method, you are free to add anything in the right and left col divs. I'll do a quick edit to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

This is example with fixed vertical line, always presented, on the middle of page. None other element will move it up or down.

```css
.vline
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    bottom:0; margin:0;
    border:none;
    border-right:solid 1px black;
    z-index:10;
}
```

```html
<hr class="vline" />
```

**Update :** There is example, based on Your edit. If that's what You need. Two `divs` floated `left` and `right`, with some `padding` and vertical divider line (`hr`)

```css
body, html {margin:0;padding:0;}
.dleft, .dright
{
    display:inline;
    width:calc(50% - 20px); /*50% width minus 2xpadding = 20px*/
    padding:10px;
}
.dleft
{
    float:left;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.dright
{
    float:right;
    background-color:lightblue;
}
.vline
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    border:none;
    border-right:solid 1px black;
    z-index:10;
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<hr class="vline" />
<div class="dleft">
    aslkjfklasdjfsadlkf
    asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>
    asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>
    asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>
    asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>
    asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>
    asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>
    asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>
    asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>
    asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>
    asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>
    asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>
    asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>asd;lfkj<br>
</div>
<div class="dright">
    aslkdjflsadkjf<br>aslkdjflsadkjf<br>aslkdjflsadkjf<br>
    aslkdjflsadkjf<br>aslkdjflsadkjf<br>aslkdjflsadkjf<br>
    aslkdjflsadkjf<br>aslkdjflsadkjf<br>aslkdjflsadkjf<br>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: If you don't want the fat (2px) border, you can change `border` to `border-left` or `border-right` since right now it's a 0px element with a 1px border on each side

Comment: Yes, instead that I can use `border:none; border-right:solid 1px black;`, for example, for `1px` `border`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fast example I've made. This is one way of achieving this.

```
<div class="verticalLine"></div>

.verticalLine {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1px;
}
```

**[Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/pkc1eLx9/)**

Another way is using absolute position like this:

```
.verticalLine {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: transitionX(-50%);
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
}
```

**[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/pkc1eLx9/1/)**

And third way without the height property

```
.verticalLine {
    background-color: #000;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: transitionX(-50%);
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
}
```

**[Example 3](http://jsfiddle.net/pkc1eLx9/2/)**

Comment: i cant add anything on both sides of vertical line, can you check the edit